# iPhone Phonegap application Landscape issue

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

I have developed an iPhone app using Phonegap. My app supports only landscape orientation. One of my html page content is not appearing properly in landscape mode.

I have added `<preference name="orientation" value="landscape">` in config.xml file. Still the issue is not solved.

How can I solve this issue?